# Eth transfer assistance help request

Tags: private-key

how can i  do the transfer from eth wallet address to another eth wallet address?
because i have a public eth wallet address with  balance within , i dont know how can i transfer the balance in order to use it on purchase.I am trying to to search for the sites like coinbase where i could be able to do this ,i dont know what can i do.I need your advise before the time while my eth balance are still in use.

Comment: Could you be more specific like what ethereum wallet are you using and what type of wallet are you trying to transfer to ? If you are using exchange sites, the answer is probably on these sites help, otherwise you can contact them. If it's about a value transaction between 2 wallet smart contracts, you have to read the doc of these contracts. If it's a simple account value transaction, you can use some wallet like Metamask or myCrypto.com